# Traversing a directory for specified folders? Qt & c++

Tags: c++, qt, directory

I got a directory with the following structur.

```
Name-
   -Year1
      -Month1
        -Day1
          -file1
        -..
      -...
   -Year2
      -Month1
      -...
   -...
```

Now i have 2 dates 2009-01-02 and 2010-02-03.

I want to  ask if anyone knows how i can list all files which are in the folders in the given time, without building a giant if-else construct.
If possible without any other frameworks than Qt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [QDir::entryList()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#entryList), which will list all the files in a folder. You can construct the directory path like so:

```
QString path = QDir::currentPath() + "/" +
               QString::fromNumber(year) + "/" +
               QString::fromNumber(month) + "/" +
               QString::fromNumber(day);
```

and then do

```
QDir dir(path);
QStringList files = dir.entryList();
```

You can do the same for the other date and then combine the two QStringLists.

Comment: Thank you for this simple solution! this way i can easily build a loop to iterate the folders within the time period.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iterator an scan the directory tree like this:

```
QDir dir("YOUR_PATH_BASE"); //"Name"
if (dir.exists())
{
    foreach(QFileInfo info, dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::Files | QDir::AllDirs ))
    {
        if (info.isFile())
        {
            //do something
        }
        if (info.isDir())
        {
            //scan again
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QDir](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qdir.html) class to do this. There you can recursively iterate over all sub-folders. To do that you can use [entryInfoList](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.6/qdir.html#entryInfoList) method. It returns a list of [QFileInfo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html) objects for all the files and directories in the directory. For every entry in this list you can check whether it is a [directory](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html#isDir) or a [file](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qfileinfo.html#isFile). If it is a directory, then you must go deeper.

Hope this helps you somehow.